# Почему функция превращается в объект?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Делаю страницу для изменения данных видео, в которой есть форма (выступает в качестве отдельного компонента, поэтому принимает пропс `fields`), где присутствует валидация.

Я хочу получить данные видео с сервера, записать их в объект `videoData`, чтобы потом заполнить начальные данные формы на странице.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда я хочу произвести проверку на валидность, то у меня выводится ошибка `fields[fieldKey].isMatchRegexp is not a function`, хотя метод `isMatchRegexp` является функцией, но после обращения к серверу данный ключ становится пустым объектом.

Данная проблема появляется тогда, когда у меня присутствует инструмент `fetch`, без него у меня все работает.

**Страница edit**

data параметры

```
data: () => ({
 fields: {
   title: {
     title: "Название",
     // Проверяет на валидность данный параметр
     isMatchRegexp(val) {
       return /.{6,}/g.test(val);
     },
     type: "text",
   },
 },
 videoData: {},
}),
```

Получение видео по id с сервера

```
async fetch() {
  try {
    const token = this.$store.getters["auth.store/getToken"];
    const { id: videoId, } = this.$route.params;
    const { ok, video, } = await this.$store.dispatch("video.store/getOne", { token, id: videoId, });

    if (ok) {
      const { poster, src, } = video;
      const validPoster = await this.getValidUrlDataFile(poster);
      const validVideoSrc = await this.getValidUrlDataFile(src);
      
      this.videoData = {
        ...video,
        video: validVideoSrc,
        poster: validPoster,
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
},
```

Запись начальных данных формы в объект fields

```
created() {
  Object.keys(this.videoData).map((key) => {
    if (key in this.fields) {
      this.fields[key].model = this.videoData[key];
    }
  });
},
```

**Компонент формы**

HTML

```
<form class="form">
<div
  v-for="(fieldKey, index) in getFieldsKeys"
  :key="index"
  class="form__field"
>
  <label
    class="form__label"
    :for="fieldKey"
  >
    <input
      :id="fieldKey"
      v-model.trim="dataForm[fieldKey].model"
      class="form__input"
      :class="{
        <!-- Здесь будет ошибка -->
        'form__input--invalid': !fields[fieldKey].isMatchRegexp(dataForm[fieldKey].model) && dataForm[fieldKey].model.length,
      }"
      :type="fields[fieldKey].type"
    >
  </label>
</div>
</form>
```

Создание подобных элементов в объекте dataForm, содержащих ключи, необходимые для проверки валидации

```
created() {
  Object.keys(this.fields).map((key) => {
    this.dataForm[key] = { model: this.fields[key].model || "", };
  });
},
```

Возвращает ключи объекта `fields`

```
computed: {
  getFieldsKeys() {
    return Object.keys(this.fields);
  },
},
```

Comment: Не вижу где вызывается `fields[fieldKey].isMatchRegexp`

Comment: @DaniilLoban, в компоненте формы у класса

Comment: если есть возможность добавьте код чтобы было видно что происходит там с `field` без этого не понять

Comment: @DaniilLoban, когда происходит? При обращении к серверу за данными видео?

Comment: там где есть строчка `fields =` или подобное

Comment: то что я вижу по данным  `fields.title.isMatchRegexp` — как минимум это странно если `fieldKey` не равен `title`

Comment: @DaniilLoban, Во-первых, если вы про запись начальных данных, то тут все верно, у меня в `videoData` есть ключ `title`. Во-вторых, почему вы решили, что `filedKey` не равен `title`? `fields.title.isMatchRegexp` - это верная запись, только метод `isMatchRegexp` превращается в пустой объект, поэтому ошибка.

Comment: что у Вас выведет в консоль `fields[fieldKey].isMatchRegexp` ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban, пустой объект

Comment: поэтому мне нужно глянуть что у Вас происходит с `fields` там где есть функция пустой объект не образуется, это нонсенс, таких превращений не бывает

Comment: по сути из приведенного Вами кода только первый фрагмент имеет значение, все остальное лишнее, а нужного то и нет

Comment: Компонент формы: https://github.com/Alexandr-web/videoPlatform/blob/master/components/vForm.vue
Страница изменения данных видео: https://github.com/Alexandr-web/videoPlatform/blob/master/pages/video/_id/_edit.vue

Comment: Так а что вообще функция в `data` делает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, проверяет на валидность значение `title`

Comment: @Alexandr_Yakovlev, ты вопрос не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исследовав отдельно файл `_edit.vue` и `vForm.vue` мне удалось обнаружить где **происходит подмена функции объектом**.

Причина действительно при использовании `async fetch` — когда она есть `Nuxt` пытается преобразовать через `stringify` данные компонента, а в данном случае функция не может пройти  такую.трансформацию, о чем сообщается в консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом после вызова `fetch` в данных лежит уже не функция:

[image: функция]

а объект:

[image: объект]

После чего я принял решение избавится от функции в объекте `fields` (если нужно использовать `async fetch`). Так как пока в проекте используется только 5 `vForm`, проще везде заменить функции на строки:

```
data: () => ({
  fields: {
    title: {
      title: "Название",
      matchRegexp: "/.{6,}/g", // <- замена функции на строку
      type: "text",
    }
  },
```

Этот формат пройдет `stringify` разумеется нужно поправить код в `vForm`, я добавил ему метод `isMatchRegexp` принимающий `reText` — ту самую регулярку как строку и `value` — значение для проверки:

```
isMatchRegexp(reText, value){
  const re = new RegExp(reText)
  return re.test(value)
},
```

Далее в двух местах заменил использование:

```
// в шаблоне

:class="{
  'form__input--invalid': !isMatchRegexp(fields[fieldKey].matchRegexp, dataForm[fieldKey].model && dataForm[fieldKey].model.length),
}"

// и в sendReq

return this.isMatchRegexp(this.fields[key].matchRegexp, itemForm["file" in itemForm ? "file" : "model"]);
```

Хочу еще заметить что метод `edit`:

```
methods: {
  edit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
```

вызываемый из:

```
this.$emit("sendReq", this.isVideo ? { ...data, ...this.video, } : data);
```

до этих правок возвращал пустой объект:

[image: пустой объект]

После, ошибки больше не возникает и в методе `edit` нормальный объект:

[image: заполненный объект]

Весь код запускался в отдельном проекте с двумя файлами `edit` и `vForm`, поэтому видео данные нигде не фигурируют, да и они в данном случае не были нужны.